# Why isn't the camera moving in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have create a child class from `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` and would like to add the ability to make the camera move around on the x,z axes, in the browser I get the position of the the from `update_position`  but the camera does not seem to move

```
class FPS extends THREE.PerspectiveCamera
{
    constructor(params) 
    {
        super(params)
        this.keys = {
            forward: false,
            backward: false,
            left: false,
            right: false,
        }
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>
        {
            console.info(this.keys);
            switch (event.keyCode)
            {
                case 87: // w
                    this.keys.forward = true;
                    break;
                case 65: // a
                    this.keys.left = true;
                    break;
                case 83: // s
                    this.keys.backward = true;
                    break;
                case 68: // d
                    this.keys.right = true;
                    break;
            }
            this.update_position();
        });

        window.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>
        {
            switch (event.keyCode)
            {
                case 87: // w
                    this.keys.forward = false;
                    break;
                case 65: // a
                    this.keys.left = false;
                    break;
                case 83: // s
                    this.keys.backward = false;
                    break;
                case 68: // d
                    this.keys.right = false;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }


    update_position()
    {
        // x axis  moves right or left
        if (this.keys.right == true)
        {
            this.position.x += 1;
        }
        else if (this.keys.left == true)
        {
            this.position.x -= 1;
        }

        // z axis  moves forward or backwards   
        if (this.keys.forward == true)
        {
            this.position.z += 1;
        }
        else if (this.keys.backward == true)
        {
            this.position.z -= 1;
        }
        console.log(this.position.x);
        console.log(this.position.y);
        console.log(this.position.z);
    }
}

class Game
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new FPS(100, window.Width/window.Height, 0.1, 1000);

    render_scene()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => 
        {
            this.renderer.render(this.scene , this.camera);
            this.render_scene();
        });
    }
}
```

if I replace `position` with `rotation` then the camera does rotate but it does not work for the position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work as expected:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, mesh;

function init() {

  camera = new FPS(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
  camera.position.z = 10;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

//

class FPS extends THREE.PerspectiveCamera {
  constructor(fov, aspect, near, far) {
    super(fov, aspect, near, far)
    this.keys = {
      forward: false,
      backward: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,
    }
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      //console.info(this.keys);
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87: // w
          this.keys.forward = true;
          break;
        case 65: // a
          this.keys.left = true;
          break;
        case 83: // s
          this.keys.backward = true;
          break;
        case 68: // d
          this.keys.right = true;
          break;
      }
      this.update_position();
    });

    window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87: // w
          this.keys.forward = false;
          break;
        case 65: // a
          this.keys.left = false;
          break;
        case 83: // s
          this.keys.backward = false;
          break;
        case 68: // d
          this.keys.right = false;
          break;
      }
    });
  }


  update_position() {
    // x axis  moves right or left
    if (this.keys.right == true) {
      this.position.x += 1;
    } else if (this.keys.left == true) {
      this.position.x -= 1;
    }

    // z axis  moves forward or backwards   
    if (this.keys.forward == true) {
      this.position.z += 1;
    } else if (this.keys.backward == true) {
      this.position.z -= 1;
    }
    //console.log(this.position.x);
    //console.log(this.position.y);
    //console.log(this.position.z);
  }
}

init();
animate();
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.145/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

The only thing I have updated in `FPS` was the constructor since the arguments were not applied correctly. Better to explicitly list the parameters.